# Return Back does work inside Excel::load() Function: Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, excel, laravel, return-value

I am trying to ***Import an Excel File into DB, after checking File Format,*** which I have done successfully, the Only Part where I am getting a problem is returning back on my view page with error or success message.

**My Controller**::

```
 Excel::load(Input::file('datafile'), function ($reader) use($attr_array) {

            ...

            //IF DATA MATCH

            if($data_match == 'true')
            {                
                    ...

                    foreach ($reader->toArray() as $row) {

                        $Pdt_data->slug = Util::uniqueSlug($row['attr_name_value'], 'Product');
                        $rem_value['slug'] = $Pdt_data->slug;
                        $resultant = array_merge($rem_value, $row);

                        //INSERT INTO DATABASE
                        Product::firstOrCreate($resultant);
                    }
                    \Session::flash('success', 'Data uploaded successfully.');
                    return Redirect::back();                   
            }               
            //IF DATA DOES NOT MATCH
            else
            {                   
                \Session::flash('error', 'You Are Trying To Import File Of Different Category!');
                  return Redirect::back();
            }
        });
```

***I had no help with Duplicate questions, Any help would be highly appreciated.***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have finally solved this problem myself by :

- Defining a variable outside Excel Function
- Pass it to function with &
- setting value of variable true or false on If Condition
- Call Redirect to URL from outside Excel Function on the basis of values set earlier.

**Updated Code:**

```
 $importstatus = ''; //DEFINING VARIABLE OUTSIDE EXCEL FUNCTION

Excel::load(Input::file('datafile'), function ($reader) use($attr_array) {

            ...

            //IF DATA MATCH

            if($data_match == 'true')
            {                
                    ...

                    foreach ($reader->toArray() as $row) {

                        $Pdt_data->slug = Util::uniqueSlug($row['attr_name_value'], 'Product');
                        $rem_value['slug'] = $Pdt_data->slug;
                        $resultant = array_merge($rem_value, $row);

                        //INSERT INTO DATABASE
                        Product::firstOrCreate($resultant);
                    }
                    \Session::flash('success', 'Data uploaded successfully.');
                    $importstatus = 'fine';    //SETTING A VARIABLE VALUE              
            }               
            //IF DATA DOES NOT MATCH
            else
            {                   
                \Session::flash('error', 'You Are Trying To Import File Of Different Category!');
                  $importstatus = 'error'; //SETTING A VARIABLE VALUE
            }
        });

//CHECK VARIABLE VALUE FOR DECISION
if ($importstatus == 'fine') {
                \Session::flash('success', 'Data uploaded successfully.');
                return Redirect::back();
            } else {
                \Session::flash('error', 'You are trying to import file of Different Category!');
                return Redirect::back();
            }
```